# Joomla calendar.setup error

Tags: joomla

Often when in the admin of Joomla, the site hangs and I get a pop up error message about nothing being found in Calendar.setup

Seems like plenty of other Joomla users have encountered this issue, all using different themes and extensions.  No answer seems to be conclusive on any forums I have searched.  Wondered if the smart brains here could sort it out? :)

Personally, I'm using Joomla 2.5 and have no Calendar extensions installed.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your WYSIWYG editor: Site -> Global Configuration -> Default Editor. After changed them, press Save.

Answer (score 0):

you need this

```
<jdoc:include type="component" />
```

Comment: please explain a little more (where? why?) for the op to fully understand your answer.